# Delay notification in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, team-foundation-server

In Visual Studio 2008 Professional, when I close the project I get the error as shown in the image below. This is a project which connects to TFS. So why do I get this message? If I click on continue it stays like that.

[image: Delay notification]

Comment: I used to run into this regularly when I was developing on a machine that had 2GB of memory.  Upgraded to 8GB and never saw it again.  Doesn't answer your question, but it solved the symptom for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645) from the [Sysinternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals).

Launch ProcMon then add a filter for `devenv.exe`:

1. `Filter` -> `Filter` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
2. Set the filter to `Process Name` `is` `devenv.exe` then `Include`
3. Click `Add`
4. Click `OK`

Launch then close VS 2008 and use ProcMon to see what it's trying (and possibly failing) to do when it closes.